# Get other aggregate values than count with Doctrine Paginator

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, aggregate, paginator

Let's say that I have an `Invoice` entity with two fields mapped to doctrine: `code` (the invoice number, like `'INV20180427'`) and `total` (the invoice total, like `19.99`).

I have a lot of invoices, so I'm using Doctrine's Paginator to display them. I create a query builder and a Paginator and then:

- I use `count($paginator)` to get the total number of results,
- I iterate over the `paginator` to get the results of the current page.

My problem is that I would also like to have **the total of all invoices** corresponding to my query (like `SELECT SUM(o.total) FROM Invoice o WHERE ...`), not just the number of invoices.

Is there a way to extend the Paginator to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can answer my own question now, so I'm gonna give it a try.
To build the `Paginator`, I use a `QueryBuilder`, so I should use this query builder to get the aggregated value:

```
$queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from(Invoice::class, 'i')
    ->select('o');

$paginator = new Paginator($queryBuilder->getQuery());

$total = $queryBuilder->select('SUM(i.total)')->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

The problem remains that if I only have access to the `Paginator`, I can't get the aggregated values I want because the `Paginator` doesn't know the `QueryBuilder` but only the `Query`.

So it would be possible to create a `CustomPaginator` class that would take a `QueryBuilder` instead of a `Query` and would have a method to get an aggregated value off this `QueryBuilder`.